# Kafka Streams - Stream on restarting after a long interval unable to read past messages from a topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I created a kafka cluster with 3 brokers and following details:

1. Created 3 topics("initial1", "initial2", "final"), each one with replication factor=3 and partitions=2.
2. Created 2 producers, producer1 pushing to "initial1" topic, producer2 pushing to "initial2" topic.
3. Created a Streams application - stream1 - to read messages from "initial1" and "initial2" topic using left join, process it and write to the "final" topic.

Following are the Stream configurations:

```
kafka.sourcetopic.one=initial1
kafka.sourcetopic.two=initial2
kafka.desttopic.one=final
kafka.stream.id=Stream11
kafka.stream.state.dir=kafka-streams-11
kafka.stream.server=PLAINTEXT://x1.x2.x3.x4:9092, PLAINTEXT://x1.x2.x3.x4:9093, PLAINTEXT://x1.x2.x3.x4:9094
kafka.auto-commit=true
kafka.auto-commit-interval=10
kafka.auto-offset-reset=latest
kafka.retries=2
kafka.retries.backoff.ms=10
kafka.request.timeout_ms=900000
kafka.timewindow_ms=36000000
kafka.schema.registry.url=http://x1.x2.x3.x4:8081
```

**Scenario-1: If both producer1 and stream1 are running**

When producer1 pushes messages(say 1000 messages) to "initial1" topic, stream1 is able to read it.

**Scenario-2: If producer1 and stream1 are stopped. After a long interval(say 10 hours), producer1 is started first and it pushes 1000 messages. After 1000 messages are pushed, stream1 is started.**

stream1 does not read those 1000 messages pushed by producer1.

**Query**

Why stream1 is unable to read past messages on restarting after a long interval? If stream is restarted during small intervals(say 5 mins), then it is able to read past messages pushed by producer1.

Comment: Try setting auto-offset-reset to none. If this causes your consumer to throw an exception, then the problem likely is that the consumer "thinks" that it has previously not read from the topic and therefore starts at the "latest" offset (since that is what you have configured it to do). If this happens, my guess is that when you start the consumer again, it for some reason comes up as a "new" consumer. Are you sure that everything is as it was before you stopped the consumer and producer? All previous messages still exist in the topic etc...

Comment: @Moonwalkr: The config "kafka.stream.id=Stream11" is same on every run of the stream so I guess it should not be coming up as a new stream. Is it possible for it to run as a new stream even with same kafka.stream.id? Also, I did check the topics and all previous messages exist. I need to check with " auto-offset-reset to none". I will test this and update here. Thanks.